# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')' - Pyodbc and SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to update some values in a database with Python 3.7 and pyodbc, but keep getting the error `Error - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'`

```
    def UpdateSQL(self,shift,conn):

        cursor=conn.cursor()
        sql="""
        UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[ZSB_Datapool_Test]
        SET AssemblyDateTime=GETDATE(),Shift_Ass=?,User_Ass='mtp1'
        WHERE(
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM [DB].[dbo].[ZSB_Datapool_Test]
        WHERE TotalResult='OK'
        AND ID=?
        AND Machinenr=?
        And Serialnr=?
        )
        """
        cursor.execute(sql,shift,self.scanID,self.scanMa,self.scanSn)
        cursor.close()
```

> File "c:\Users\mmai\Documents\Python2\Scanner\Scanner.py", line 228,
>   in UpdateSQL
>       cursor.execute(sql,shift,self.scanID,self.scanMa,self.scanSn) pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]In der Nähe von ')' wurde ein nicht
>   boolescher Ausdruck in einem Kontext angegeben, in dem eine Bedingung
>   erwartet wird. (4145) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Anweisung(en) konnte(n) nicht vorbereitet
>   werden. (8180)")

Comment: Look at your where clause. You have a subquery there but you are basically saying "Where MySubQuery". You are missing the other side of the equation. Where MySubQuery = X

Comment: Thank you `WHERE EXISTS(..)` did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `EXIST` next to `WHERE` solved it. Thank you Sean Lange.

Comment: That's interesting *params* worked when not bound in a tuple or list: `cursor.execute(sql,[shift, self.scanID, self.scanMa, self.scanSn])`

Comment: @Parfait - That's a [pyodbc feature](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#passing-parameters).